# How to use joins in JPQL constructor expressions?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a data model with Customers, which each have n Portfolios, which in turn have n Investments, both mapped as @ManyToMany and lazily fetched.

I also have a DTO with just the following fields:

- customer name
- list of portfolio names

Is it possible to write a single JPQL query that creates the DTOs using constructor expression? Especially how would you get list of portfolio names in the DTO constructor?

Is it inefficient if I instead query for Customer models with portfolios and construct the DTOs myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it by yourself, and it will probably even be slightly more efficient than using a constructor in JPQL, since reflection won't be necessary:

```
select c.name, p.name from Customer c left join c.portfolios
```

Then loop over the results, and construct your results. For example:

```
Map<String, Result> results = new HashMap<String, Result>();
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    String customerName = (String) row[0];
    Result r = results.get(customerName);
    if (r == null) {
        result.put(customerName, new Result(customerName));
    }
    r.addPortfolio((String) row[1]);
}
Collection<Result> namesAndPortfolios = results.values();
```

Comment: thanks! So in general using constructor expressions is not more efficient, then? Just more convenient in simple cases?

Comment: It has to invoke the constructor via reflection, so my assumption is that it will be slightly less efficient. But the performance difference is negligible compared to the time taken to execute the query.